# Gitlab CICD: Pipeline pending/stuck due to tag

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have problem with gitlab cicd - yml file

Here's what I'm aiming, When I release tag on main/master pipeline should run but in my case its stuck.

my sample yml code:

```html
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-1-build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker 
    - test-runner
  script:
    - git status
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
    - export
  only:
      refs:
        - tags
  when: manual
```

Here's my runner settings

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01jzq.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htalX.png)

and the pipeline

[Pipeline status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQvAP.png)

I tried also the $CI_COMMIT_TAG and still when I run the pipeline stuck.

What should I edit or check to fix the problem?

Comment: Your runner will take jobs from only from protected branch, is your branch main (or master) set as protected ?

Comment: Is your GitLab runner with those tags actually running and registered to your project? If you open your project settings -> CICD -> runners; do you see your runner there with a green checkmark?

Comment: Hello Guys, its been a month. I already figure it out. :D thank you